# Option to leave part of a searchable report/form blank in Microsoft access

Tags: sql, forms, report, ms-access-2007

I have a query in MS `Access` that is linked to a searchable report which is linked to a form. Part of the report ask users to include two reasons that will be used as criteria for a query. Currently, the report (screenshot) below does not allow for users to simply enter in 1 reason. Users must enter in 2 reasons, and if the reasons are the same, users must enter in the same reason for both fields. For example, If I only have one reason (conflict of Interest),I would need to enter that reason into both reason boxes shown on the screenshot below. I would like to be able to search for one reason while also being able to leave the other reason box blank. So simply entering in Conflict of interest for one box and have it run the query. The code I have for the query is below.

```
SELECT C1.ConsultID, C1.Consult_No, C1.Consult_Type, C1.Intake_Date, C1.Adult_Peds, C1.Title, C1.ConsultSummary
FROM ([Intersection Query Pre-Reasons] AS C1 LEFT JOIN tblConsultReasons AS C2 ON C1.ConsultID = C2.ConsultID) LEFT JOIN tblConsultReasons AS C3 ON C2.ConsultID = C3.ConsultID
WHERE (((C2.Reason)=Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason1) And ((C2.ReasonType)="Discerned")) And (C3.Reason)=Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason2 And C3.ReasonType="Discerned";
```

How would you recommend I change the code in order to do this. I believe adding a length condition to the second half of the where clause may work. But am not sure what this would look like.

[Screenshot of part of the searchable report that queries on reasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6VIf.jpg)

Comment: What do you want the query to do when two separate (different) reasons are entered: return all items where EITHER Reason1 or Reason2 matches?

Comment: When two separate (different) reasons are entered, I would like it to return all items where BOTH reason1 and reason2 matches. So I believe an "AND" search instead of an 'OR' search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something like this; I haven't tested it because that requires building forms etc and I don't have the time atm:

```
SELECT C1.ConsultID, C1.Consult_No, C1.Consult_Type, C1.Intake_Date, C1.Adult_Peds, C1.Title, C1.ConsultSummary
FROM ([Intersection Query Pre-Reasons] AS C1 
      LEFT JOIN tblConsultReasons AS C2 ON C1.ConsultID = C2.ConsultID) 
      LEFT JOIN tblConsultReasons AS C3 ON C1.ConsultID = C3.ConsultID
WHERE
    NOT (nz(Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason1,'')='' And
         nz(Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason2,'')='' 
        )
    And (
           (nz(C2.Reason=Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason1,'')='' 
            And C2.ConsultID is null) 
            Or
           (nz(C2.Reason=Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason1,'')<>''  And
            C2.Reason=Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason1 And 
            C2.ReasonType="Discerned")
        )           
    And (
           (nz(C3.Reason=Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason2,'')='' 
            And C3.ConsultID is null) 
            Or
           (nz(C3.Reason=Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason2,'')<>''  And
            C3.Reason=Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason2 And 
            C3.ReasonType="Discerned")
        )
```

It can be simplified a bit if we know the data available, and other controls/checks the search boxes may have.

Comment: Hey tinazmu, The code you provided worked great. However, it is returning data for all the reasons and not the selected identified reason. Is there a way to fix this.

Comment: I have made a small correction to the join condition. It is very hard to troubleshoot when I can't reproduce the problem. Can you provide test data for these tables, and the search criteria you used for the two form fields (Forms!FrmReasonsCriteria!Reason1, Reason2) when you observed returning rows for ALL reasons?

Comment: The data types for consultno and consultid are numbers. For consult type, title, and adult peds it is a string with a drop down of choices and for intake date it is a date. The search criteria I used was simply one reason code in the form fields. For example, searching for the reason 'conflict of interest' returned results not just pertaining to conflict of interest.

Comment: would the use of a len operator perhaps be more useful than NZ?

Comment: In the setup I was able build it worked ok, that's why I said maybe you should give me some data for the tables. I am happy to delete this answer so that someone else can answer. Just let me know.